# Versioning different directories in one git repository?

Tags: git

I want to version multiple logically related directories in one git repository. This is mainly used on windows server 2012R2.

Imagine I develop an imaginary web application that consists of:

1. php files in a webserver's htdocs directory (d:\server\htdocs*.php)
2. python scripts called by the php files (d:\pythoncode*.py)
3. xml config files for some 3rd-party server module (d:\module1\abc\d*.xml)

What is a good way to do this? I do not want separate repositories because all of the above are related and need to be versioned together. I found [Maintaining unrelated directories in one git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933864/maintaining-unrelated-directories-in-one-git-repository) but it is old and does not have a satisfying answer. Is there an update on this, e.g. using any kind of links? Something like the following?

```
- git_repo_root
|-- php/    --> d:\server\htdocs\
|-- python/ --> d:\pythoncode\
|-- xml/    --> d:\module1\abc\d\
```

Note that all directories are on the same partition in this example, but a solution for different partitions is much appreciated, too.

Comment: Make multi git repos and then group those repos using another repo that imports the original ones using submodules

Comment: This really doesn't feel like a source code issue. It's not clear what your end game is here, but something release pipelines is probably a better solution

Comment: I want to avoid submodules if possible, because one set version of the software *always* consists of *all* of the directories (or to be precise, certain files in all the directories). A single directory, which would be a separate git repository / submodule, is never viable on its own, nor used separately in any other project. Using separate repositories would mean more sources for errors (e.g. incompatible submodule versions), as well as more overhead for branching, and for managing repositories on our gitlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are planning to do development directly on the live system. Unless you are just working on a throw away prototype, that's most probably not a good idea.

Instead, set up a local development environment where you are free to configure the paths for the different file types in which ever way you want or need. Do the versioning only in this local work environment.

One way to configure the development setup would be to use links. Just flip the links in your example:

```
- git_repo_root
|-- php/    <-- d:\server\htdocs\
|-- python/ <-- d:\pythoncode\
|-- xml/    <-- d:\module1\abc\d\
```

Deploy the files needed to run the application to the live system whenever you reach a stable state with added functionality compared to the previous increment. In the most simple scenario, such a deployment can be done with a script that copies the files to their appropriate places, for example via SSH.

By having this kind of separation, **the directory structure of the deployed files on the live system will be *decoupled* or independent from the directory structure within your Git repository**, so that the need for versioning directories in multiple locations outside of the Git repository's root directory vanishes.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Development is done on a system we use for development and internal (developer) testing.

But yes, the files are atm edited directly in their target locations that mirror production, so e. g. a deployment step for testing is not neccessary. This is done because many of the changes made don't require a real deployment, restart etc. (editing configuration files, complex schemas etc.).

Comment: I see, I amended the answer to suggest how you could use links in your dev environment in a way that avoids having to split the project files into different Git (sub-) repositories.